# How to check if a file exists in C from user input

Tags: c, file, input

I'm a complete noob to C and I wondered why if I take a user input why it wont find the file but when I hard code it using:

```
const char * fn = "/Users/james/Documents/test.rtf";
```

It seems to work fine?

```
char text[100];
fputs("File location: ", stdout);
fflush(stdout); 
fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin);

FILE *fp = fopen(text,"r");
if( fp ) {
    printf("\nFile Exists");
    fclose(fp);
} else {
    printf("\nFiles doesn't exist");
}
```

Any help would be awesome, or just a point to some online source that I have clearly not been able to find.
:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets` reads a line and keeps the final newline character. You'll have to strip that off by

```
text[strlen(text) - 1] = '\0';
```

(After doing the proper error checking, of course.)

Comment: Brill thank you, I had read somewhere about that now but in a slightly different context so at least now I know. I will mark you as correct in 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use access() to check whether file exists or not
For access you need to provide path of the file and mode.

Prototype of access is 
int access(const char *pathname, int mode);

access() returns zero if file exists.

For more information visit: http://linux.die.net/man/2/access